# Why I ve some missing value doing a PRCC analysis after LH sampling?

Tags: r

That's my latin hypercube sampling of an epidemiological model:

```
parameters <- c(Beta = 1.8, gamma_h= 1/7, alpha= 5, Beta2= 3, mu_m= 1/8, C= 1000, p= 0.6)
```

lhs<-maximinLHS(100,length(parameters))

```
Beta.min <- 0.1
Beta.max <- 6
gamma_h.min <- 1/10
gamma_h.max <- 1/4
alpha.min <- 3
alpha.max <- 7
Beta2.min <- 1
Beta2.max <- 6
mu_m.min <- 1/12
mu_m.max <- 1/6
C.min <- 500
C.max <- 2000
p.min <- 0.3
p.max= 0.9

LHS_SIRV.uniform  <- cbind( Beta = lhs[,1]*(Beta.max-Beta.min)+Beta.min,
                 gamma_h = lhs[,2]*(gamma_h.max-gamma_h.min)+gamma_h.min,
                 alpha = lhs[,3]*(alpha.max-alpha.min)+alpha.min,
                 Beta2 = lhs[,4]*(Beta2.max-Beta2.min)+Beta2.min,
                 mu_m = lhs[,5]*(mu_m.max-mu_m.min)+mu_m.min,
                 C = lhs[,6]*(C.max-C.min)+C.min, 
                 p = lhs[,7]*(p.max-p.min)+p.min)
```

Then after that I want to do a partial rank correlation coefficient. For that I create a dataframe of parameters and main output :

```
parameters <- c(Beta = 1.8, gamma_h= 1/7, alpha= 5, Beta2= 3, mu_m= 1/8, C= 1000, p= 0.6) 

init <- c(S_h= 65000, I_h = 1, R_h=0, D_h= 0, S_m= 30000, I_m= 1)  
SIRV <- data.frame(matrix(rep(NA,100),nrow=100, ncol= ncol(LHS_SIRV.uniform)+3)) 
colnames(SIRV)<-c(names(parameters), "MaxInf", "MaxDur", "Thresh1")
```

Then when I do the prcc procedure:

```
prcc_size <- pcc(SIRV[,1:length(parameters)], SIRV$MaxInf, nboot = 500, rank=TRUE, conf=1-bonferroni.alpha)
```

I ve the return :

```
"[1] "All values of t are equal to  1 \n Cannot calculate confidence intervals"
```

There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50".

```
Call:
pcc(X = SIRV[, 1:length(parameters)], y = SIRV$MaxInf, rank = TRUE,     nboot = 500, conf =
1 - bonferroni.alpha)
```

Partial Rank Correlation Coefficients (PRCC):

```
       original bias   std. error  min. c.i.  max. c.i.
```

Beta             NA   NA           NA         NA         NA

gamma_h  0.66456921   NA           NA  0.3298834  2.3285923

alpha   -0.73157883   NA           NA -2.4631431 -0.4668000

Beta2   -0.01338792   NA           NA -1.0265995  0.9730587

mu_m    -0.72973840   NA           NA -2.4591508 -0.4602121

C                NA   NA           NA         NA         NA

p        1.00000000    0 8.375662e-17         NA         NA

Why Beta and C are NA ?????

Moeover when i do the same thing but with `prcc_duration <- pcc(SIRV[,1:length(parameters)], SIRV$Thresh1, nboot = 500, rank=TRUE, conf=1-bonferroni.alpha)`
I ve no problem :

Partial Rank Correlation Coefficients (PRCC):

```
       original        bias std. error   min. c.i. max. c.i.
```

Beta    -0.41777323  0.28176673  0.7894458 -1.83554646 0.1644535

gamma_h  0.51049624 -0.14188507  0.7348207  0.02099249 2.0209925

alpha    0.59870283 -0.06944773  0.6952997  0.19740566 2.1974057

Beta2   -0.11555968  0.10389373  0.7790595 -1.23111937 0.7688806

mu_m     0.65873910 -0.24657407  0.7308407  0.31747820 2.3174782

C       -0.06936082  0.19371286  0.7691380 -1.13872163 0.8612784

p       -0.34604591  0.10394436  0.7436426 -1.69209181 0.3079082